# Finding AppDelegate.m file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to find `AppDelegate.m`'s absolute path if we know full path of .xcodeproj file?
I'm writing a desktop app for integration of some lib into xcode project, and for doing that I need to add some initialization code in `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

What I've tried.
1. Search and read `main.m` file in parent dir of selected .xcodeproj to find AppDelegate's class name (i.e. parsing class name from `NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])` line).
2. Now, when I know `AppDelegate`'s class name, I search for `AppDelegate.m` file in root folder of the project. At first glance everything seems ok. But if we have integrated, say Facebook sdk, then our search result will be multiple, cause there is some sample projects in Facebook sdk with theirs own `AppDelegate.m` files. And in this case I can't know which one of these `AppDelegate`'s belongs to the current project.

I also tried to parse project.pbxproj file, but can't find nothing useful.

So how I can find absolute path of `AppDelegate.m` file if I know a full path of `*.xcodeproj` file?

Comment: I'm confident it's all there in the .pbxproj file; what do you mean by "can't find anything useful"? It should list all files and paths that are part of the build, linking various sections via GUIDs.

Comment: Can you please give some example of how to parse and find it programmatically?

Comment: I've thrown everything I can think of into an answer but, as it strongly implies, I've never actually done the programmatic footwork; I've just spent years dealing with merge conflicts in that thing. Apologies for not being able to go further.

Comment: Can you [swizzle](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) `didFinishLaunching`?  You don't need to inject code into your user's AppDelegate.m if you can just create an NSApplicationDelegate category that swizzles the method you want to add something to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were Xcode I would probably:

1. open the project.pbxproj
2. find the `rootObject` line. It looks like it's usually the last one but don't rely on that. Get the GUID. E.g. in the file I'm presently looking at it's `rootObject = 29B97313FDCFA39411CA2CEA /* Project object */;`
3. follow the GUID to find the project object. In my case the opening line looks like `29B97313FDCFA39411CA2CEA /* Project object */ = {`. Within that object look for the `targets`. Mine has two, one for the main project, one for the tests, supplying two further GUIDs;
4. look up the targets. E.g. one of mine opens with `1D6058900D05DD3D006BFB54 /* ProjectName */ = {`. Collate the list of all `buildPhases` from those;
5. look up the GUIDs of all the build phases and compile the internal lists of `files` (which are identified by yet more GUIDs);
6. look up each file by GUID and grab the `fileRef` GUID;
7. from each file ref get the `path` (which is only a suffix) and the `sourceTree`;
8. find the object with `isa = PBXGroup` that has that named source tree and hence get the path prefix;
9. combine prefix and suffix to get full path.

That would give me a full list of all files included in all project targets. I could try skipping straight to step (7) by filtering on `isa = PBXFileReference` but that would include files that were listed in Xcode but not included in any target.

In 99.9999% of cases, only one file in the project will contain a class that implements `UIApplicationDelegate`.

As an alternative strategy I might decide to inspect the build product:

1. call `xcodebuild` to build the project;
2. interrogate the objects where `isa = PBXFileReference` with `explicitFileType = wrapper.application` to get the output names;
3. call `otool -ov <output binary>` and inspect the output for whomever implements the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol;
4. find that class in the candidate list.

Or, taking charge of clang myself, I might:

1. deploy libclang ([obligatory Mike Ash link](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-01-24-introduction-to-libclang.html)) on each source file in turn, traversing the AST for protocol conformance declarations.

... about which I'm being vague because I've never used libclang rather than due to some grossly misplaced attempt to be coy.